# Checklistbox issue displaying selection in message box

Tags: c#

I am having an issue getting the checkedlistbox to display all selections in a message box for a windows application. I am only getting the last one selected to display. For example, I select "one, three, and five", only five displays.

Here is my code:

```
       string display = "";
       foreach (object selectedItems in clb.CheckedItems)
       {               
           if (clb.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
           {
               display = "Items needed\n-----------\n\n\n" + selectedItems.ToString();
           }
            else
           {
               display = "No items selected";
           }  
       }
          MessageBox.Show(display, "Title");
```

Any ideas to point me in the right direction to accomplish this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the loop that starts before the test of the number of items selected/checked. Your loop continues changing the value of the variable display at each loop.  At the end the variable contains only the last item checked/selectd.

So, I assume that you want to display the checkeditems, not the selecteditems.
In any case you need to loop over the collection (ChekedItems in this case) and accumulate in a stringbuilder the item texts that you want to display.

```
string display = "";

// Every item in this collection is an item 
// with CheckState = Checked or Indeterminate
if (clb.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(string item in clb.CheckedItems)
        sb.AppendLine(item);
    display = "Items needed\n-----------\n\n\n" + sb.ToString();
}
else
{
    display = "No items checked";
}  
MessageBox.Show(display, "Title");
```

If you really want to loop on the selecteditems, the code is the same, but just use the SelectedItems collection

Answer (score 0):

you need to concat the selected items like `display +=` or better to use [Stringbuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

```
display += " Items needed\n-----------\n\n\n" + selectedItems.ToString();
```

OR you can do as below

```
if(clb.CheckedItems.Count >0)
   display = "Items needed\n-----------\n\n\n" + string.Join(",", clb.CheckedItems.Select( i=>i.ToString()));
else
  display = "No items selected";
```